# What is $2^{(k+1)} +2^{(k+1)}$ equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am so confused with this question. When the powers add we get $2^{2k+2}$ but in my book it says $2^{k+2}$.

How is that? Please explain.

Comment: Most functions are not additive. In other words, they do not satisfy $f(a) + f(b) = f(a+b)$. This is a common mistake students make. In practice, this only holds for functions of the form $f(x) = mx$.

Comment: Note that you have two (2) copies of $2^{k+1}$, namely, as others have pointed out: $2⋅2^{k+1}$. Note that the exponent $k+1$ denotes multiplying 2 by itself $k+1$ times. If we multiply one more two in, then we are multiplying $k+2$ times over. In other words $2^{k+2}$.

Comment: The powers add when you multiple terms.  Here you are add in terms so there is nothing to be expected with adding.  However adding two things is the same as multiplying by 2.  As the base is two *now* you add and you add one.  Try it with n=2.  $2^3+2^3=8+8=17=2^4;  2^3+2^3=2*2^3=2^4$

Comment: Would you take two tens in change for a hundred? $10+10=10^1+10^1=10^2=100.$

Comment: @fleablood you have a typo: $17$ should be $16$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't add the powers like that: $2^a+2^b$ is *not* the same as $2^{a+b}$.

What is true is that $2^a\cdot 2^b = 2^{a+b}$.

For your particular problem, we have $2^{k+1}+2^{k+1} = 2\cdot 2^{k+1} = 2^1\cdot 2^{k+1} = 2^{1+(k+1)} = 2^{k+2}$.

Answer (score 5):

$2^{k+1}+ 2^{k+1}=2 \cdot 2^{k+1}= 2^{k+2}$